# Matrixrank returns the matrix only and doesn't tell rank

Tags: matrix

I've defined a matrix "a={{1,1},{2,2}}" and I tried finding out its rank by "Matrixrank [a]", however it only gives output "Matrixrank{1,1},{2,2}}". I tried several different matrices, as well as symbolic ones, but it doesn't tell the rank. Also, Matrixform doesn't give matrix in matrix form, if that helps. I'm using Mathematica 12.1 trial version.

Comment: Try `MatrixRank` !

Comment: It is `MatrixRank` not `Matrixrank`.  Case-sensitive.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You got me by a few seconds. LOL!

Comment: Thank you, problem solved!

Comment: @Edmund My answer was a little bit shorter to gain time...  ;-)

Comment: The syntax coloring of `Matrixrank` is blue indicating that it is undefined. Highlight `Matrixrank` and press `F1` for help. The first link is for `MatrixRank`